# My application have two dropdown list ,Min age and Max age. Dont want to allow Max age value less then Min age value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdownbox

In my ASP.NET MVC application I have two dropdown lists, min age and max age. I don't want to allow selection of max age dropdown values less then the min age dropdown values

My view:

Dropdown List 1 Min age:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MinAge, new SelectList(ViewBag.agelist, "AgeValue", "AgeValue")
```

Dropdown List 2 Max age:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MaxAge, new SelectList(ViewBag.agelist, "AgeValue", "AgeValue"))
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult PartnerPreference()  
 {
     ViewBag.agelist = mdal.AgeList.ToList < AgeList > ();
     return View();
 }
```

I need to put a condition in my application is, not allow to select values from max age dropdown list values < (less than) min age dropdown list...

```
Minage: { 20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30 }

Maxage: { 20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30 }
```

For example:

```
If end-user select the min age vale of 25 from the Min age dropdown list 
then it should not allow max age dropdown values less then min age values.(select only above 25 values {25,26,27,28,29,30}).
```

How to write the code to put condition and validation message in my web application?

I hope you understand my question.

Thank You

Comment: Use a conditional validation attribute, for example a [foolproof](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof) `[GreaterThan()]` attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(collection["MinAge"]) > Convert.ToInt32(collection["MaxAge"]))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Min Age should be greater than Max Age");
            return View(cl);
        }

        // TODO: Add insert logic here

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

You can retrieve MinAge and MaxAge from the FormCollection, then you can compare them, if MinAge is greater than MaxAge then you add an error to the Model, which will display an error to the end user